# Почему jQuery выводит 0, а также NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код ниже считает за 2 секунды от 0 до заданного числа. Как сделать так, чтобы считало числа от 0 до 12,456 – то есть возвращать число с запятыми?

```
var currentNumber = 0;
var simple = '<?php echo $g_kill; ?>';
$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: simple}, {
duration: 2000,
step: function() { 
    $('.fot-global-txt').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
}
});
```

Выводит NaN

Comment: работает же http://jsbin.com/hirawodeba/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Нее если var = 12,234,123 то это получается NaN.

Comment: Можно как то исправить?

Comment: Jean Я хочу сделать так чтобы она вращяла число 12,345 то есть от нуля идет на число 12,345.Если с запятой не получется то с точкой

Comment: @Sauron вам наоборот надо избавиться и от запятых  и от точек в `simple` ....

Comment: По другому не как? мне нужно именно с запятыми вращял от 0 до числа.

Comment: Вроде нашол отдельный плагин какойто http://aishek.github.io/jquery-animateNumber/ Она вращяет всё что угодно

Comment: Она даже лучше работает чем я считал )

Answer (score 1):

```js
var currentNumber = 0;
var simple = '30000';
var $el = $('.fot-global-txt');
$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: simple}, {
  duration: 2000,
  step: function() {
    var v = Math.ceil(this.numberValue)
      .toString()
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
    $el.text(v);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fot-global-txt"></div>
```